# vector analysis and reduce to a general expression in theta's

Tags: vector-spaces, vector-analysis

$\vec{A},\vec{B},\vec{C}$ and $\vec{D}$ are unit vectors ($|A|=1,|B|=1,|C|=1$ and $|D|=1$). The angle between the vectors,

1) $\vec{A}$ and $\vec{B}$ is $\theta_{1}$ ($\vec{A}.\vec{B}=\cos\theta_{1}$)

2) $\vec{B}$ and $\vec{C}$ is $\theta_{2}$ ($\vec{B}.\vec{C}=\cos\theta_{2}$)

3) $\vec{C}$ and $\vec{D}$ is $\theta_{3}$ ($\vec{C}.\vec{D}=\cos\theta_{3}$)

4) $\vec{D}$ and $\vec{A}$ is $\theta_{4}$ ($\vec{D}.\vec{A}=\cos\theta_{4}$) 
and

5) $\theta_{1}+\theta_{2}+\theta_{3}+\theta_{4}=2\pi$.

The objective is to make a relationship between $\theta$'s (As an example $\theta_{1}+\theta_{2}=\pi$). Also there is one relationship with the vectors.

\begin{equation}
(p+q+r)(\vec{A}+\vec{B}) + (p+q)\vec{C} +r\vec{D}=0
\end{equation}

$p,q,r$ are constants. How would I do that, So far I worked like this,

I take the dot product of vector $(\vec{A}-\vec{B})$ (because $(\vec{A}-\vec{B}).(\vec{A}+\vec{B})=0$) with above equation,

\begin{eqnarray}
(p+q+r)(\vec{A}+\vec{B}).(\vec{A}-\vec{B}) + (p+q)\vec{C}.(\vec{A}-\vec{B}) +r\vec{D}.(\vec{A}-\vec{B})=0 \\
(p+q)\vec{C}.(\vec{A}-\vec{B}) +r\vec{D}.(\vec{A}-\vec{B})=0 
\end{eqnarray}

Is that possible to reduce above equation in terms of $\theta$'s?

Comment: Just a suggestion: try to accept one of the answers provided to your questions. This will increase your chance to get answers for the next time.

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören I can't see any answer. Did some one write the answer?

Comment: I am telling you the reason.. and I am not talking about this question, but the previous questions of you. You asked 8 question and out of 8 you got answers to 6 of your questions and in total 8 persons wrote you answers. However you have never accepted any of them. Now what is the motivation behind answering your question?

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören Sorry, I didnt know that I need to accept those. hik hik.

Comment: I will personally not. Because I didn't answer your questions. However the person who answers your question will. There is also quite much information about these issues in meta exchange. Accepting an answer shows your respect to the person who answers it. It is like saying you are stupid to your teacher and still expecting answers to your next questions. Definitely your teacher would not be happy with this)